# ajax is not receiving the same string as it is sent from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, string

I'm experiencing some problems when I am checking value in my ajax call which was returned from my PHP file.

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_record.php",
        data: {
                record_id:data[0]
              },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) 
        {
            alert(response);                                         
            if(response=='ok')
            {
                alert("Record has been deleted");
            }
        }
        });
```

**PHP:**

```
//some php codeing....
//echo at the bottom
echo 'ok';
```

I have also tried

```
echo filter_var('ok',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo trim('ok');
```

but I'm not receiving true in this line: `if(response=='ok')`

EDIT:
I forgot to wrote that I am getting `ok` as a response from the server script

Comment: Check whatever is returned from your server in your developer console.

Comment: `alert(response)`. What does  it say?

Comment: Is there any additional spaces before / after `<?php ... ?>` ?

Comment: You might have some whitespace somewhere, And i'd recommend u create some object in server side and json encode it for this types of actions, would be easier to add more data afterwards

Comment: make `console.log(response)`. What do you get?

Comment: guys I'm receiving only `ok` from `alert` and `console.log`

Comment: You may debug the whole script in your developer tools..
Press F12 and check in Script tab..

Comment: You are probably getting `" ok"` or similar as your response - from whitespace in your php file, or something it includes.

Comment: if there are some whitespaces, try using if($.trim(response)=='ok')

Comment: @BojanKovacevic please write an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @user123_456 i did it. And i am glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem can be that response has whitespace(s). Use jQuery function [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
 if($.trim(response)=='ok') 
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try client side (jquery) trim instead of server side (PHP),

Try following script,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_record.php",
        data: {
                record_id:data[0]
              },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) 
        {
            response = $.trim(response);                                         
            if(response=='ok')
            {
                alert("Record has been deleted");
            }
        }
        });
```

for your reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/